# split dictionary from list dictionary into separate row python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have output like this:

`[{'faculty': 1, 'now': 1}, {'fa': 1,  'now': 1}]`

How to split dictionary from list dictionary into separate row python 
like I want my comma separated value as output stored like this  row-wise

```
[{'faculty': 1, 'now': 1}]
[{'fa': 1,  'now': 1}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by row wise? You want to print every element of the list in a seperate line?

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
x = [{'faculty': 1, 'now': 1}, {'fa': 1, 'now': 1}] 

[[item] for item in x]
# [[{'faculty': 1, 'now': 1}], [{'fa': 1, 'now': 1}]]
```